# Continuous martingale with specific Q.V. is a brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have a continuous martingale $X_t$ starting from zero, with quadratic variation

$$[X_t,X_t]=ct$$.

I want to show that $$W_t=c^{-1/2}X_t$$ is a brownian motion.

How can we get from the quadratic variation to the independence of increments and $E(W_{t_1}-W_{t_0})=t_1-t_0$?

Comment: This is essentially just immediate from a very well-known standard theorem known as Lévy’s Characterisation of Brownian Motion. See [here](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/levys-characterization-of-brownian-motion/) for example.